# how to exclude from group condition

Tags: go, go-gorm

I know how to create grouping condition but what make me frustrated is trying to put condition outside existing grouping condition

i am doing this with gorm:

```
func Abc(db *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
  return db.Where("company_id = ?", "j37977c5-0825-481f-b472-2g2gc234cbc5")
}

salesman := new(Salesman)

db.Scopes(
   Abc,
).Where(
   db.Where(
        "code LIKE ?",
            "%"+val+"%",
        ).Or(
            "name LIKE ?",
            "%"+val+"%",
        ).Or(
            "active",
            val,
        ).Or(
            "join_on",
            val,
        ),
).Find(salesman)
```

result query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM `salesmen`
WHERE
(
 code LIKE '%0%'
 OR name LIKE '%0%'
 OR active = '0'
 OR join_on = '0'
 AND company_id = 'j37977c5-0825-481f-b472-2g2gc234cbc5'
)
AND deleted_at IS NULL
```

but what I want is the query to be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `salesmen`
WHERE
(
  code LIKE '%0%'
  OR name LIKE '%0%'
  OR active = '0'
  OR join_on = '0'
)
AND company_id = 'j37977c5-0825-481f-b472-2g2gc234cbc5'
AND deleted_at IS NULL
```

which exclude or put company_id condition outside conditional grouping just like deleted_at
how to do that?